# Macro for multiline text

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet where in one column Header name 'LOTZ' multiline goods name are listed in single cell (goods quantity changes e.g day 1 have 7 goods & day 2 may have 1 good). I need to create Top 50 Goods in entire year with respective count in separate sheet.

**Example :-**

[image]

**Result I want in new inserted sheet:-**

[image]

i am able to use DATA tab 'text to column' but don't know how to consolidate via macro code.

any help will be highly appreciated.

thanks monika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub consolidate()
    Dim r As Range, dict As Object, lotz
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each r In Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns("C").Offset(1).Cells
        For Each lotz In Split(r.value, vbLf)
            dict(lotz) = dict(lotz) + 1
        Next
    Next
    With Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A1:B1").value = Array("LOTZ", "Count")
        .Range("A2:A" & dict.Count + 1).value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
        .Range("B2:B" & dict.Count + 1).value = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
        .Range("A2:B" & dict.Count + 1).Sort .Range("B2"), xlDescending
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT

If the column of `lotz` is not known and you want to find its header in row 1, you can use this instead:

```
For Each r In Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Find("LOTZ").EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(1)
```

Comment: Thanks can you suggest a way when position of LOTZ sheet changes. Means find header LOTZ and run on column

Comment: Also sorting the count to descending order

Comment: Code also give header count i.e. LOTZ=1

Comment: @monikasingh I think the edited code answers your requests.

Comment: yes it does a wonderful job - one last input can we raname the added sheet to LOTZ

Comment: @monikasingh you can add `.name = "LOTZ"` after the `With Worksheets.Add`. Only problem is you cannot overwrite it, you will need to delete it or rename it each time you run again the macro.

Comment: are you available on freelance basis?

Comment: if yes reach me at mo21singh@gmail.com